Squaring Inequalities Conclusion
While studying inequalities, I came to a conclusion about the effect on the sign when inequality is squared on the both sides.
The points I noted were-

Sign remains same when both sides are non-negative.
Sign remains same when the moduli of both sides respectively hold the same inequality as the original inequation.
In all other cases, the sign is flipped on squaring the inequality.

Am I getting it right? Are there any other points I can include?
Does this apply to linear inequations only, or to all?
Thank You for your time.

I'd change the first one to Sign remains same when both sides are non-negative

In fact, the first point is redundant (as the modulus of a positive number is just the original number). But yes, you are correct. If the moduli satisfy an inequality, then so do the squares. Otherwise, the inequality is flipped. And linearity is not relevant here, it is merely a fact about numbers.

@AntonyTheo. Agreed.

@infinitylord Got it! Thank you.
